# Programming readability with strings

Tags: .net, vb.net

While working on a project I have come across a way of not having to check if a string `isnull` or `empty`

```
dim sb as new stringbuilder
dim bob as string

sb.append((bob & string.empty).padLeft(10, " "))
```

Here, `bob` is not instantiated but doesn't throw a null reference error. In situations like this, is it more readable to do the above code or the below code?

```
if string.isnullorempty(bob) then
  sb.append(string.empty.padleft(10, " ")
else 
  sb.append(bob.padleft(10," "))
endif
```

I personally think method #1 is more readable and maintainable. What does the community feel?

Comment: Using `&` depends on its implementation that could change.

Comment: The code has a bug.  It forgot to initialize "bob".  You are trying to find a way to hide bugs.  Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [If()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) with two parameters to select the first non-null value, e.g.

```
If(bob, string.empty).padLeft(10, " ")
```

Comment: +1, this clarifies the pseudo-conditional state (which is actually string concatenation?) nicely

Comment: i forgot about the semi turnary way of doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your audience. If you have experienced developers such tricks are acceptable. A new developer will definitely get confused by the first example.

A good guide is this:

- Would you know a week from now what the code does? Yes -> Ok
- Do you need to comment what it does? Yes -> Not Ok
- Will there be new developers in the team that might not understand this code? Yes -> Not Ok

In the end its your call. I would understand and accept the first example.

Answer (score 0):

An even better solution.

```
if not string.isnullorempty(bob) then
     sb.append(bob)
endif
sb.append(New String(" "c, 3)) ' ten spaces
```